# Loading data from RData files into a single data table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rdata

I'm trying to load data from **data frame** objects of **all** `.RData` files in a specified directory into a **single data table**. This is how I've tried to do this:

```
library(data.table)

fileList <- list.files("../cache/FLOSSmole", pattern="\\.RData$", full.names=TRUE)
dataset <- rbindlist(lapply(fileList, FUN=function(file) {as.data.table(load(file))}))
```

However, **the result** is different from the expected (single data table containing all **data**) - it contains just **names** of data frame objects from the source `.RData` files:

```
> str(dataset)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  39 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "lpdOfficialBugTags" "lpdLicenses" "lpdMilestones" "lpdSeries" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> head(dataset)
                        V1
1:      lpdOfficialBugTags
2:             lpdLicenses
3:           lpdMilestones
4:               lpdSeries
5:             lpdProjects
6: lpdProgrammingLanguages
```

**What am I doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated!**

**My R environment:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.1   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: @Arun: Thank you for cleaning up the tags list.

Comment: A much easier, faster and simpler way is to use `fread` instead of `.Rdata`. `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))`...

Comment: @Arun: I have seen this code earlier when researching the topic, but my understanding is that `fread()` is a `data.table`'s alternative for `read.table()`. If I collect data from original sources and want to store it efficiently as an application's cache (`.RData` or `.rds`), I still have to use `save()` and `load()` or `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`, correspondingly, don't I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.RData` is a saved workspace, it may contain data frames, but it is not a data frame. How many data frames are there in each `.RData`? You can load multiple `.RData` files and they add to the current workspace. Just load them all then `merge` or `rbind` the data.frames once they are in your current workspace

```
# lapply(FileList,function(x) load(x)) # Changed to a for loop, I guess the lapply was only loading into the lapply environment which disappears when the function ends
for (i in 1:length(FileList)) {
   load(FileList[i])
}
my.list <- vector(length(ls()),mode="list")
for (i in 1:length(ls())) {
    my.list[[i]] <- get(ls()[i])
}
my.rbind <- do.call(rbind,my.list)
```

This is one way. An easier way would be to save individual tables as delimited text files in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Currently, each `.RData` file contains a single data frame. I left such design for this piece of code (instead of using `.rds` files for storing single objects, as I do in other places), as I plan to implement a single multi-object `.RData` file solution. I do merge data tables, but after converting data frames to data tables first. So, what's wrong?

Comment: `.RData`, even if it only contains a single data.frame, can't be used as though it was a data.frame.

Comment: `load(.RData)` adds .RData to your current workspace. You need to call `as.data.table` on the data.frame within that workspace, not on the load command.

Comment: I see. I guess, I understand now... The underlying reason for my problem is that `load()` returns "a character vector of the names of objects created". But how do I get the reference to a data frame object to pass to `as.data.table()`? I'm thinking about using `get()` for this.

Comment: I'm confused: when I call `load()` on an individual `.RData` file, corresponding data frame is loaded into my global workspace, but when I do the same for all files via `lapply()`, no data frames are loaded.

Comment: I changed it to a for loop which is often better for modifying something in the global environment and added how to make a list of the data frames after you load them. Moral of the story: individual `.RData` files is not wise.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, I was right about `get()` - at least, I'm not completely lost in the ocean of `R`, but sometimes I feel that way... :-). Accepting your answer and thank you again!

Comment: In regard to your note on saving individual tables, the whole point of my efforts to merge data is to make it easier to access/query data that I need for further statistical analysis.